# How to redirect all call to another application with web api

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET application with web api controllers and angular client. I call to web api in the next way:

```
this.$http.get('api/menu/get', {
                params: {}
            })
```

So I call to absolute path like http://myApp/api/menu/get. And now I should get some data from another web application, url example: http://secondApp/reportsApi/reports/get.

How to get data from secondApp web api?
As I know I can just call absolute path from UI like

```
this.$http.get('http://secondApp/reportsApi/reports/get', {
                params: {}
            })
```

But it doesn't looks like good decision. I wont to make calls like:

```
this.$http.get('reportsApi/reports/get', {
                params: {}
            })
```

And in some way redicrect this calls from "myApp" to "secondApp".

Comment: why would you do this client side? you should set up proxy pass in the server.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wrong some where in description, but it's exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how. How can I set up proxy pass in the server to redirect only calls like 'reportsApi/reports/get'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This describes how you can use the built in IIS rewrite modules.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

You will end up with something like this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect Reports Api" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^reportsApi/reports/get" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://secondApp/reportsApi/reports/get" />
      </rule>
    <rules>
  <rewrite>
<system.webServer>
```